# .py which uses input files to .exe

Tags: python, exe, executable-path

I have a python script in which I am using the input files which are either pickle files or excel files. the output files are then saved in the drives. I need to convert the py into exe files. Being a new bee i am not able to understand how to create exe files and then how to handle these cases.

part of the codes i am mentioning where i have used the excel files as an input and output.

Please note that i have not created it as a project as well.

```
customer_data = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/sonia/Downloads/book1.xlsx", sheetname = "Sheet1", heading = 0)
customer_data.set_index("Chassis no ", inplace = True)

data_in_form_reqd = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/sonia/Downloads/Accidental case.xlsx",sheetname = ["Customer_Info", "Insurance_Info"], heading = 0)
data_in_insurance_form_reqd = data_in_form_reqd["Insurance_Info"]
data_in_insurance_form_reqd.set_index("Short Name", inplace = True)


data_in_form_reqd = data_in_form_reqd["Customer_Info"]
data_in_form_reqd["Entry Name"] = data_in_form_reqd["Short Name"] + "_1"          
data_in_form_reqd.set_index("Short Name", inplace = True)
```

...............................
    c_i_data_exisiting = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/sonia/Downloads/Accidental case.xlsx", sheetname = "Sheet4", heading = 0)

```
c_i_data_exisiting = c_i_data_exisiting.append(c_i_data)

c_i_data_exisiting = c_i_data_exisiting[['servicing_dt',     'V_No',     'M_No',     'YoP',  'Cust_N',   'Cust_E'   , 'Cust_Mo' , 'Cust_Wh',     'yesno'    , 'i_name',  'i_pol_no',     'i_mail',   'Doc_Sub_dt'   , 'exp_est_date'    , 'est_cost'    , 'act_ext_dt'  , 'parts_avail' , 'mail_send_dt_to_i_comp',  'mail_response_dt_from_i_comp',     's_name'   , 's_mobile',    's_mail',   's_whatsapp',   'call_dt_to_surveyor',  'est_dt_of_survey',     'act_dt_of_survey',     'survey_agreement',     'act_dt_all_party_agreement'   , 'st_dt_repair',    'surveyor_follow_up',   'act_dt_all_party_agreement_follow_up',     'est_dt_to_complete_repair',    'act_dt_of_completion' , 'final_dt_of_survey'  , 'dt_of_collecting_bike',   'feedback' , 'status'   ,'impt',    'Sr_Mgr',   'St_Mgr'   , 'Ins_Lead'     ,'Mechanic'    , 'comment']]


c_i_data_exisiting.to_csv("C:/Users/sonia/Downloads/axlsx.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: What's the error/problem?

Comment: I do not know how to create exe and second even if i create it how would it handle the path provided. I need to share the exe files with someone without python Thanks Alderven